# Constructor parameter and local variable

Tags: javascript

I don't know why constructor parameter and local variable can use same name?

```
function Book(name){
  var name = name;
  this.getBookName = function(){
    return name;
  }
}

var book = new Book("Test Book");
document.write(book.getBookName());
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Because `book` !== `Book` and `BooK` !== `Book` and ... JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean "var name = name; " this statement

Comment: Well that is bad coding... the browser just ignores the bad syntax. If you were running in strict mode, there would be a problem.

Comment: They don't use the same name **at the same time**. Local variable replaces parameter once it defined

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works that way, you will never get an error when **re-declaring** any variable. In JavaScript names are case-sensitive, which means that: `a != A`

By the way, you're using getter method, why don't you use setter method to control changes to variable?